# Using underscore to group a objects properties into separate smaller objects based on a name

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Currently I have a object that has multiple keys that are prefixed with a "_id(actually a number)", like a so:

```
    var obj = {
outFieldType_25669: "Select a type"
outFieldType_97327: "Select a type"
outfieldWallType_25669: "Select a type"
outfieldWallType_97327: "Select a type"

scoreboardDetailsShown_25669: "e.g. players name, photo, stats, etc..."
scoreboardDetailsShown_97327: "e.g. players name, photo, stats, etc..."
scoreboardOperatedBy_25669: "Select a type"
scoreboardOperatedBy_97327: "Select a type"

warningTrackType_25669: "Select a type"
warningTrackType_97327: "Select a type"
};
```

What i would like to do is split that object into smaller objects that are grouped by the ending prefix, a example of what the outcome is envisioned to be:

```
objA = {
    outFieldType_97327: "Select a type",
    outfieldWallType_97327: "Select a type",
    scoreboardDetailsShown_97327: "e.g. players name, photo, stats, etc..."
    scoreboardOperatedBy_97327: "Select a type",
    warningTrackType_97327: "Select a type"
};

objB = {
   outFieldType_25669: "Select a type",
   outfieldWallType_25669: "Select a type",
   scoreboardDetailsShown_25669: "e.g. players name, photo, stats, etc...",
   scoreboardOperatedBy_25669: "Select a type",
   warningTrackType_25669: "Select a type"
};
```

Comment: I don't think underscore will help here. It's not complicated to do it manually, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `_.each` to iterate the object, `split` the id from the key and store it in a separate object, e.g.

```
var sorted = {};

var obj = {
    outFieldType_25669: "Select a type",
    outFieldType_97327: "Select a type",
    outfieldWallType_25669: "Select a type",
    outfieldWallType_97327: "Select a type",
    scoreboardDetailsShown_25669: "e.g. players name, photo, stats, etc...",
    scoreboardDetailsShown_97327: "e.g. players name, photo, stats, etc...",
    scoreboardOperatedBy_25669: "Select a type",
    scoreboardOperatedBy_97327: "Select a type",
    warningTrackType_25669: "Select a type",
    warningTrackType_97327: "Select a type"
};

_.each(obj, function (value, key) {
    var id = key.split("_")[1];
    if (sorted[id] === undefined) {
        sorted[id] = {}
    };
    sorted[id][key] = value;
});

console.log(sorted);
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UMnp9/).

Comment: Oh, you killed the fun for him :).